# Angular Dart and Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, dart

I'm currently using angular dart and it's great. The basic set of components are handling a large portion of the requirements.

Some Angular components that I'd love to incorporate into the app only have Typescript versions. Is there a converter or process that allows me to port TS components?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use Typescript component with Angular Dart, it's like 2 different technology.

You can take a look at the old Typescript to Dart transpiler (https://github.com/dart-archive/ts2dart) but don't know if it still works (it's from the time when Angular Dart was generated from Typescript source).

However, you can reuse CSS/HTML from Typescript component and Angular concept are the same. For simple components you would just have to convert Typescript syntax to Dart syntax.

Comment: Hi,
I see that you are an expert in Dart, so can you give me an advice please ?

I'd like to learn a new frontend framework but I'm confused between AngularDart and Angular (typescript).
In fact I'd like to work with dart language that's why I tend to AngularDart but I find it not very used all over the world and no enough tutorials exist.

What do you suggest , can you give me an advice please ?